# Manipulating CSS properties of groups tr elements in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have grouped the table into two groups with group 1 consisting of the first two columns and group 2 consisting of the remaining columns as shown below:

```css
#table tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#table tr {
  display: table-row;
}

#table td:nth-child(1),
#table td:nth-child(2) {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  /* Make the first two columns in the same group */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#table td:nth-child(3),
#table td:nth-child(4) {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Team</td>
      <td>Region</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Game</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red Sox</td>
      <td>AL East</td>
      <td>MLB</td>
      <td>Baseball</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to transpose the appearance of each of these groups using the css display inline-flex with a column flex-direction property the same way we can do for the table, i.e.,

```
#table tr {
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: column;}
```

However I am unable to figure out on how I will access each groups tr elements so that I can manipulate their css properties in order to solve my problem.

Comment: maybe you can use flex boxes/ grid boxes instead of using a table to your issue that way you can easily manipulate your boxes however you want.